# Invisible text inside input IE8

Tags: input, internet-explorer-8, modal-dialog

I met some magic behavior of IE8. There login form inside a dialog, text inside the input is not shown immediately when user enters it but after some time. The cursor is moving but text is invisible. It happens only for inputs that inside a dialog, inputs just on page works well. For showing dialog the following bootstrap function is used `$dialogElement.dialog('show')` do you have any ideas, why it happens? I can provide more details if needed.

Thanks

PS

Here is the [site](https://photofeed.com) where you can notice the problem in the Login dialog

And here is an [example](http://screencast.com/t/w3K1RkvO5Kn) of the behaviour

Comment: I know it sounds dumb ... but don't you have a white text with a white background, do you? If not plz provide a link.

Comment: If you could recreate this issue in a fiddle, or give a code example, that might help understand the problem, and make it easier to solve. If you could provide that, I'll have a look.

Comment: I would like that it be so easy, but no, it is not a white text, and all works nice on other browsers. I even cannot reproduce it on IE8 emulator mode in IE9, only on original IE8. You can try to reproduce it here photofeed.com in login dialog.

Comment: Just a thought: could it be a bug in the placeholder polyfill script?

Comment: No, I tried to remove placeholder from the inputs, still the same problem.

Comment: "magic behaviuor". You're very kind with IE8. Most other people whoud have used different words to define the behaviuor... :-)

Answer (score 1):

After searching for the same kind of problems, I found two possible solutions. You might try following these. If that doesn't work, I'm not sure if I can do much more for you, without being able to access the css.

[Passwords showing up as white (or not at all) in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199471/passwords-showing-up-as-white-or-not-at-all-in-ie)

[Dynamic Elements are not appearing in IE8 until there is a mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350441/dynamic-elements-are-not-appearing-in-ie8-until-there-is-a-mouse-click)

Let me know if either of these solutions work out for you.

---

As stated in my comment, another solution could be to hide the pop-up using javascript, instead of using `display: none;` in CSS. This way, the element gets rendered by the browser first, after which it will be hidden. If it is hidden through CSS, the element will not be rendered, untill it is shown.

In your case, that means that you could remove the following CSS

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

and hide the element `.hide` via javascript, right after the page loads.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but it doesn't work for me. First only for password but I have problem with regular input either. The second - doesn't help. By the way. I just realized that text is shown but extremely slow in modal window. Link to video is added to the question

Comment: You could try to hide the element in javascript, instead of via CSS, on initialisation. This way, the elements get rendered first, and hidden after, instead of not rendered at all at first. If that's not helping, then I'm not sure I can really help, without seeing the code, and being able to edit it.

Comment: Bootstrap modal is used, and it changes visibility of container with javascript just as you said. You can see it on the page if inspect element `'#loginDialog'`, element.style is changed not css class. But still, thanks for the guess

Comment: That is not what I meant. When the page is loaded, the element is not shown, because it is hidden by CSS. After the page is loaded, it get's shown with javascript when the link is clicked. However, because the element was hidden on page load, it was not rendered yet. If you hide the element just after the page loads, it will render first, and then get hidden. This might solve your problem.

Comment: I got what you meant, modal is visible by default but has `opacity:0`, and placed out of the screen `top:-25%`. So it should be renedered after page loads, am I right?

Comment: #loginDialog is hidden on page load via .hide. If that would be visible on page load, the problem might be solved.
So if you would remove display: none; from .hide, and hide div's with the class hide via javascript, that might solve it.

Comment: No, it didn't help, still the same.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an answer per-se but I'll improve it as more details will be given because...

I just tried your site on my testing virtual machine with Windows XP, IE8.

**Your login form (the one you show on the screencast) works just fine. No issues at all.**

The text (and bullets on password field) appears just as I type.

---

Are you on Windows XP or newer OS? Have you tried on different machines/VMs?

Could it be an issue of your environment setup?

(I can't help until I'm able to replicate the mis-behaviuor).

---

BTW: It may turns out, trying on different environments, that only on few setups the problem appears while on most IE8 setups it doesn't.

It could depend on the graphic board, some DLL or configuration files missing, misconfigured, corrupt... all the things that usually causes problems on Windows machines.

In that case you may consider ignoring the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is funny, but I also cannot reproduce it on virtual machine, only on machine with installed win XP, don't ask my why, it just happens, magic!

Comment: Well... send me the phisical machine. Are you far from Italy? :-)   (I updated my answ.)

Comment: I'm from Belarus, but the problem appears on tester side in India. maybe problem is linked with particular OS, I will try investigate this option. Thanks.

Comment: Just tell the tester to test the site on a clean (fresh installed) machine or virtual-machine. He most likely won't see any problem and you're done.

Comment: Maybe in a perfect world. But if bug can be reproduced on this particular machine - it could be reproduced on other one. I'm agree that it is not critical, but quite annoying.

Comment: I mean: if the machine have issues (ex. is broken, is out of ram, disk full, outdate graphics card drivers...) the problem is not on the site. Differently if the problem can be reproduced on other machines with normal, acceptable configuration the problem is on the site.

Answer (score 0):

From [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum) at [Dropdownlist text is invisible in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678419/dropdownlist-text-is-invisible-in-ie8/16678459#16678459)

> IE8 does not support the textContent property. You have to shim for it and use innerText instead.
>
> ```
> option.textContent = option.innerText = departments[i][1];
> ```

Comment: I don't use textContent property so it is not a cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this problem as well and the problem for me was that one of parent elements was 'absolutely positioned' (i.e. position: absolute).

I noticed that the login dialog is no longer on your homepage but maybe this might help someone else. Say that you have this structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="dialog">
    <!-- dialog content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And you experience the invisible text issue in IE8, try adding:

```
<style>
  .container {
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Yes. I have updated my comment to include the fix for my situation.